# How to create an event loop in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, bluetooth, event-loop

I'm trying to use the `CoreBluetooth` module to list all the detected Bluetooth devices in a command-line OSX application.

What I have looks like this, so far:

```
@import CoreBluetooth;

@interface MyCentralManager : NSObject<CBCentralManagerDelegate>
- (void) centralManagerDidUpdateState: (CBCentralManager *) central;
- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *) central
    didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *) peripheral
        advertisementData:(NSDictionary *) advertisementData
                     RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI;
@end

@implementation MyCentralManager
- (void) centralManagerDidUpdateState: (CBCentralManager *) central
{
    NSLog(@"State changed...");
}

- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *) central
    didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *) peripheral
        advertisementData:(NSDictionary *) advertisementData
                     RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSLog(@"Discovered %@", peripheral.name);
}
@end

int main() {
    MyCentralManager* myCentralManager = [[MyCentralManager alloc] init];
    CBCentralManager* cbCentralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:myCentralManager queue:nil options:nil];

    NSLog(@"Scanning devices now !");

    [cbCentralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
    sleep(5); // Wait 5 seconds before stopping the scan.
    [cbCentralManager stopScan];

    NSLog(@"Scanning devices ended.");

    return 0;
}
```

Now this doesn't work at all as I never get any `"State changed..."` nor `"Discovered ..."` log output.

I never actually written any Objective C application before so I'm probably missing the obvious. If I had to guess what I'm doing wrong I would assume that:

- [I actually have to wait for the `CentralManager` to be in the appropriate state before starting the scan](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks.html).
- I never actually get inside the state changed delegate method so I assume that my first mistake is: instead of just `sleep()`'ing, **I have to run an event loop of some sort so that the underlying system has a chance to notify me of the state change.**

I'm basically stuck at this point: I don't have a GUI, nor do I want one but couldn't figure out a way to run an event loop (assuming that's actually what is missing). How can I do that ?

*As I said, this is actually my first attempt with Objective C, so don't be afraid to state the obvious.*

Comment: It's possible that your MyCentralManager instance is not being retained since the delegate property CBCentralManager is declared as weak. If you override dealloc in your manager class, is it called before scanning completes?

Comment: @PatrickGoley Would have any link/reference on this ? I'm not sure what would cause in my code the property to be weak.

Comment: It's not your code that's causing it to be weak, if you look at the header for CBCentralManager, you'll see its delegate property is declared as weak and that's the only reference pointing to your manager instance

Comment: @PatrickGoley Okay I get it. Thanks for the explanation !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply run the thread's run loop

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5]];
```

More information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1).

BTW: You do not have to declare the methods already declared in the protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I haven't had a chance to test that out yet, but will shortly.

Downvoter, would you care to explain your vote ? Why do you think this is wrong ?

Comment: An Idiot:- 2 1 hour ago downvote  
-2 1 hour ago downvote Objective-C : appending a NSString to NSException reason
-2 1 hour ago downvote how to validate amount text value
-2 1 hour ago downvote NSObject Class initialisation
-2 1 hour ago downvote categories vs utility classes in iOS
-2 1 hour ago downvote Integer value of NSPopUpButton Selected Item
-2 1 hour ago downvote TDD in Objective-c: property/constructor injection or method swizzling?
-2 1 hour ago downvote Delete Specific Items from NSMutableArray
-2 1 hour ago downvote Adding Strings to NsMutableSets

Comment: I take it you were victim of serial downvote ? You should mention it on meta if nobody picks it up before (there are mechanism to detect such lame behaviors)

Comment: I think the script will repair it.